# Why doesnt (click) sends my data inside <button>, but (change) inside <input> does in Angular, HTML

Tags: html, angular, typescript, http

I want to send some data to my Glassfish RESTful server. When I use (change) inside the input tag it activates the method and succesfully sends the data, but when I use (click) or (change) to activate the method, it doesn't do anything. I tried to seperate the Sending data method and the router method, but to no avail.
 How can I solve this?

html file:

```
<div class="container py-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
          <div class="card rounded-0">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h3 class="mb-0">Organize</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="codes" class="m-2">Choose a restaurant:</label>
              <form #f="ngForm">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  list="codes"
                  class="m-2"
                  (change)="saveCode($event)"
                  >
                <datalist id="codes">
                  <option *ngFor="let c of codeList" [value]="c.name">{{c.name}}</option>
                </datalist>
              <button
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-primary btn-lg float-none m-2"
                id="btnAanmaken"
                (click)="routerRed()"
              >Aanmaken</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

typescript file:

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {NgForm} from "@angular/forms";
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from "@angular/common/http";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-organize',
  templateUrl: './sendinvite.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sendinvite.component.css']
})
export class SendinviteComponent implements OnInit {

  // public codeValue: string;

  // List of restaurants
  codeList = [
    { name: 'Mcdonalds', address: 'Kalverstraat 5' },
    { name: 'Kentucky Fried Chicken', address: 'Kalverstraat 4' },
    { name: 'Burger King', address: 'Kalverstraat 3' },
    { name: 'Dominos pizza', address: 'Kalverstraat 2' },
    { name: 'New York Pizza', address: 'Kalverstraat 1' }
  ];

// Assign empty value to id, name and address
  @ViewChild('f', { static: true }) form: NgForm;


  restaurant = {
    name: ' ',
    address: ' '
  };

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json',
      Authorization: 'my-auth-token'
    })
  };


  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

// Method to post data to backend
  public saveCode (e): void {
    const name = e.target.value;
    const list = this.codeList.filter(x => x.name === name)[0];


    this.restaurant.name = list.name;
    this.restaurant.address = list.address;

    console.log(list.name);
    console.log(list.address);


// Additional information to the server content type
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json'
      })
    };
// Making an array with the values of the restaurant
    const data = {
      name: list.name,
      address: list.address
    };

    console.log(data);

// POST method
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/aquadine-jee/resources/restaurant',
      JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)) , httpOptions)

    // wait till it gets posted to the backend
      .subscribe( // subscribe to observable http.post
        res => {
          console.log("response" + " " + res); // log results otherwise log error
        },
        err => {
          console.log('Error occured');
        }

      );


  }

  routerRed(){
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/menu');
  }
```

I tried to use:

```
<button 
                type="submit" 
                class="btn btn-primary btn-lg float-none m-2" 
                id="btnAanmaken"
                routerLink="/menu"
                (change)="saveCode($event)"
                >Aanmaken</button>
```

and:

```
<button 
                type="submit" 
                class="btn btn-primary btn-lg float-none m-2" 
                id="btnAanmaken"
                routerLink="/menu"
                (click)="saveCode($event)"
                >Aanmaken</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `(change)` event inside the button is going to do nothing, the `(click)` is more appropiate, but the `$event` passed inside the click event is going to return the information about the click itself (mouse position, etc).

What you should do is, whenever click is called, get the value of the form and send that to the `saveData` function. (Maybe by doing something like `saveData(this.f.value)`, but I can't tell with certainty)

I don't have experience with template driven forms, maybe it's worth for you to take a look at [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#introduction-to-reactive-forms), it is going to make your life easier IMHO

Answer (score 0):

The `(change)` event will not be triggered on the click of a button as there is no "change" as such. You should use `(click)` instead. The reason why your `saveCode()` is not being invoked when you set both `routerLink` and `(click)` is because of the `routerLink`. When you click the button, Angular is navigating to `/menu` before it triggers your click event. You can navigate from your component in your `saveCode()` instead.

Since you also have an API call in your `saveCode()`, it would probably be better if you navigate on success as it might not make sense to re-route the user if the API call fails (especially if the new route depends on the saved data)

Try this in your code.

**HTML**

```
<button type="submit"
  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg float-none m-2"
  id="btnAanmaken"
  (click)="saveCode($event)">
  Aanmaken
</button>
```

**component**

```
.subscribe( // subscribe to observable http.post
  res => {
    console.log("response" + " " + res); // log results otherwise log error
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/menu');
  },
  err => {
    console.log('Error occured');
  });
```

**Edit**: Rather than using `$event` to pass your values to the component, you can make use of the `ngForm` you have used in your code along with ngModel.

**component**

```
<input type="text"
  list="codes"
  class="m-2"
  name="restaurantName"
  ngModel
>
```

**component**

```
  @ViewChild('f', { static: true }) form: NgForm;

  ...

  public saveCode (): void {
    const name = this.form.value.restaurantName;
    ...
  }
```

Here is another example from the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#listening-for-form-submission) on how to bind values to the form using ngForm and ngModel

Comment: Are you trying to get the button value in this line ````const name = e.target.value;````?

Comment: when I print out that value to the console, it prints out the selected restaurant name in the datalist

Comment: Your question is still not very clear. You are calling the API when you select a value from the dropdown. Do you want to continue doing that or send the value only on the click of the button? If you are trying to the latter, you will not be able to get the value of the dropdown using ````e.target.value````.

Comment: I am trying the latter, I want to send data when the button is clicked. How do I get the selected value from the dropdown?